# Two constructors for a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to have two different constructors for the same `Fragment` ?

Here's my case : I have `Fragment_A` and `Fragment_B` which are almost identically, except one gets an Integer and the other a String.

Can I have something like this :

```
public static VideoListFragment newInstanceA(String filterString) {
    VideoListFragment myFragment = new VideoListFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(FILTER, filterString);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}

public static VideoListFragment newInstanceB(String subjectId) {
    VideoListFragment myFragment = new VideoListFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(POSITION, subjectId);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

If this is possible then how am I going to get in `onCreate()` the argument ? I have somehow to check if getArguments()` contains FILTER String or POSITION Integer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an exact same method signature to distinguish between different input behaviors. However, you can extend input parameters to make it more versatile. Something like this would help:

```
public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {    
    public static VideoListFragment newInstance(String type, String val) {
        VideoListFragment myFragment = new VideoListFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(type, val);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);

        return myFragment;
    }
}
```

and later use it as below:

```
VideoListFragment frag1 = VideoListFragment.newInstance(FILTER, "value");  //for Filter
VideoListFragment frag2 = VideoListFragment.newInstance(POSITION, "value");//for Position
```

Comment: But I have different names : `newInstanceA` and `newInstanceB` . Will it work like this? Otherwise, your answer is a good alternative option for me.

Comment: Yes, if you provide separate names then it will work, but that is unnecessary redundancy for such a minor thing to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Android docs discourages the use of constructors while working with fragments; you should use bundle instead.

Comment: any reference to that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: @DEEPANKURSADANA You cannot override no-args constructor anyhow, as it will fail with an error.  However, if you want, you may use a constructor as long as it has one or more input parameters.